# Can a Widget plugin upcast an anchor tag without link plugin interfering?

Tags: ckeditor

When upcasting a Widget plugin, existing elements that should get upcasted in the textarea on init are not being upcasted when they are anchors. They are instead "upcasted" by the link plugin. When disabling the link plugin, the anchor elements are still not upcasted by the widget.

Perhaps anchor element is an exception for Widget plugins? Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

Anchors are touched by an older mechanism called [fakeobjects](http://ckeditor.com/addon/fakeobjects). This mechanism runs independently from widgets and thus there's conflict. Some elements, in order to be editable, are replaced with images with special attributes.

The line that is responsible for the transformation of empty anchors to fake objects is this one - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/a99d4d33b09397c1ec91cdd573d7d54335a5c944/plugins/link/plugin.js#L184

There's no option to disable that other than removing this line of code (or disabling plugin as you know). Another solution could be to trigger the opposite transformation inside your upcast method (if you discovered that this fake object was an anchor earlier), however, that requires [few lines of code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/a99d4d33b09397c1ec91cdd573d7d54335a5c944/plugins/fakeobjects/plugin.js#L30-L52).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Instead of wrangling with this conflict I think I might go with the strategy of making the outermost element of the widget a div and put an anchor on the inside. See the template property I'm using here -> https://github.com/rjsteinert/ckeditor-plugin-linkbox/blob/master/plugin.js#L17

Do you think that's going to cause any conflicts like the ones you mentioned? So far so good with testing this strategy, keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: AFAIR `dataProcessor.dataFilter` (used by the link plugin) is applied to the whole content before widget upcasting. So I'm afraid that the anchor is turned into a fake object before your upcast method is called. However, if that's not a problem for you that inside your widget you'll have a fake objects, then it might work. The `dataProcessor.toDataFormat()` method performs downcasting before applying `dataProcessor.htmlFilter`, so after your widget is downcasted, the fake object that was inside will be decoded to an anchor. At least I hope so :D